# wordpress sticky post on archive page with pagination

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have category page which is redirecing to archieve.php.

> you can see here : https://www.dealfinder.lk/category/dining/

There are **two** sticky posts at the top.

1) Up to 25% OFF at &Co Pub and Kitchen with COMBANK Cards

2) 20% OFF at Robata – Movenpick Hotel Colombo for all HSBC Credit Cards

**My pagination is 10 items per post**

Right now, it shows me **12 items per post**.

Here is my code :

```
function yell_category_sticky_posts( $posts, $wp_query ) {

    global $wp_the_query;

    // Don't continue if this isn't a category query, we're not in the main query or we're in the admin
    if ( ! $wp_query->is_category || $wp_query !== $wp_the_query || is_admin() )
        return $posts;

    global $wpdb;

    $q = $wp_query->query_vars;

    $page = absint( $q['paged'] );

    if ( empty( $page ) )
        $page = 1;

    $post_type = $q['post_type'];

    $sticky_posts = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );

    if ( $wp_query->is_category && $page <= 1 && is_array( $sticky_posts ) && !empty( $sticky_posts ) && ! $q['ignore_sticky_posts'] ) {

        $num_posts = count( $posts );

        $sticky_offset = 0;

        // Loop over posts and relocate stickies to the front.
        for ( $i = 0; $i < $num_posts; $i++ ) {

            if ( in_array( $posts[$i]->ID, $sticky_posts ) ) {

                $sticky_post = $posts[$i];

                // Remove sticky from current position
                array_splice( $posts, $i, 1 );

                // Move to front, after other stickies
                array_splice( $posts, $sticky_offset, 0, array( $sticky_post ) );

                // Increment the sticky offset.  The next sticky will be placed at this offset.
                $sticky_offset++;

                // Remove post from sticky posts array
                $offset = array_search( $sticky_post->ID, $sticky_posts );
                unset( $sticky_posts[$offset] );

            }

        }

        // If any posts have been excluded specifically, Ignore those that are sticky.
        if ( !empty( $sticky_posts ) && !empty( $q['post__not_in'] ) )
            $sticky_posts = array_diff( $sticky_posts, $q['post__not_in'] );

        // Fetch sticky posts that weren't in the query results
        if ( !empty( $sticky_posts ) ) {

            $stickies__in = implode( ',', array_map( 'absint', $sticky_posts ));

            // honor post type(s) if not set to any
            $stickies_where = '';

            if ( 'any' != $post_type && '' != $post_type ) {

                if ( is_array( $post_type ) )
                    $post_types = join( "', '", $post_type );

                else
                    $post_types = $post_type;

                $stickies_where = "AND $wpdb->posts.post_type IN ('" . $post_types . "')";
            }

            $stickies = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT wp_posts.* FROM $wpdb->posts INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) WHERE 1=1  AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (" . get_term( $wp_query->query_vars['cat'], 'category' )->term_taxonomy_id . ") ) AND $wpdb->posts.ID IN ($stickies__in) $stickies_where" );

            foreach ( $stickies as $sticky_post ) {

                // Ignore sticky posts are not published.
                if ( 'publish' != $sticky_post->post_status )
                    continue;

                array_splice( $posts, $sticky_offset, 0, array( $sticky_post ) );

                $sticky_offset++;

            }
        }
    }

    return $posts;

}
add_filter( 'the_posts', 'yell_category_sticky_posts', 10, 2 );
```

**My Issue:**

> I want to show **10** posts per page, currently it shows **12** posts
>   per page with sticky post.

This question is for master not for new learner.

Anybody master here? Thanks in advance

Comment: The source code of this old plugin didn't provide any solution? https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/category-sticky-post/

Comment: It would be very complicated unless you save 'sticky posts' in a meta, query using that key and order by its value (already proposed in https://wordpress.org/ideas/topic/change-sticky-posts-from-an-option-field-to-a-meta-field-in-the-database).

Comment: @OutsourceWordPress Thanks your reply. I have already used "radio button" meta key (is_featured_post). there was radio button as two value (1 and 0). it was working as per query document. I fetched post for both calue 1 and 0. But I want to random post which are set as "0". Hope you understand my issue.

Comment: Yep, I'll update a solution for you.

Answer (score 4):

The below function pushes stickies to the top, you should be able to use this to help in your case.

```
add_filter('the_posts', 'bump_sticky_posts_to_top');
function bump_sticky_posts_to_top($posts) {
    $stickies = array();
    foreach($posts as $i => $post) {
        if(is_sticky($post->ID)) {
            $stickies[] = $post;
            unset($posts[$i]);
        }
    }
    return array_merge($stickies, $posts);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I suggested in the comment, save the 'sticky posts' in **meta** (assuming `is_featured_post` as the 'meta key').

Run these **only once** to set the meta value for existing posts. You can skip this since you are already saving in the meta.

```
// set meta value of all posts to 0
$all_posts = get_posts(array('post_type'=>'post','posts_per_page'=>-1));
if( is_array( $all_posts ) )
{
    foreach( $all_posts as $post ) {
        update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'is_featured_post', '0'  );
    }
}

// set meta value of all sticky posts alone to 1
$sticky_posts = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
if( is_array( $sticky_posts ) )
{
    foreach ( $sticky_posts as $sticky_post ) {
         update_post_meta( $sticky_post, 'is_featured_post', '1'  );
    }
}
```

The below function will update the new sticky meta `is_featured_post` each time a post updated (or new post saved).

```
function save_sticky_meta( $post_id ) {
    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['sticky'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'is_featured_post', '1'  );
    }
    else {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'is_featured_post', '0'  );
    }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_sticky_meta' );
add_action( 'edit_post', 'save_sticky_meta' );
```

Then use `pre_get_posts` action to set the category query. We are ordering by both 'meta' and 'date' descending to show the latest at top.

```
function include_sticky_posts( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_category() ) {
        $query->set( 'meta_key', 'is_featured_post' );
        $query->set( 'sticky_sort', true ); //custom sticky order query
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num date' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'DESC' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'include_sticky_posts' );
```

If you want to randomize non-sticky posts, change the order using `the_posts` filter as below.

```
add_filter( 'the_posts', 'sticky_posts_sort', 10, 2 );
function sticky_posts_sort( $posts, $query )
{
    // if custom sort set from category query
    if ( true !== $query->get( 'sticky_sort' ) )
        return $posts; 

    // loop through posts & save sticky & other posts in seperate arrays
    $sticky_posts = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
    $sticky_array = array();
    $posts_array = array();
    foreach ( $posts as $p ) {
        if( in_array( $p->ID, $sticky_posts ) )
            $sticky_array[] = $p;
        else
            $posts_array[] = $p;
    }

    // merge both arrays and randomize non-sticky posts alone
    if( is_array( $posts_array ) )
        shuffle( $posts_array );
    if( is_array( $sticky_array ) && is_array( $posts_array ) )
        $posts = array_merge( $sticky_array, $posts_array );
    elseif( is_array( $sticky_array ) )
        $posts = $sticky_array;
    else
        $posts = $posts_array;

    return $posts;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I appreciate it. This will resolve almost all issue. but I want posts randomly listed which are not featured post. you are using ('order', 'DESC') which will listed my posts descending order. I want to make my post lists random which posts are not "featued".  I have gone through query document: there is variable "orderby-> rand" . It I use "rand" variable, featured posts are not coming as first. Hope you understand my responsce. Thanks

Comment: Yes, understood now, let me check a solution.

Comment: But please note that non-sticky posts displayed per page only gets randomized and not the whole.

Comment: Thanks for your updated answer. Its close to my solution