# Wordpress: Show Sticky Post on page.php

Tags: wordpress

i have a wordpress website about a sportclub with different sport discipline. For each discipline i have an pageX.php-Template and a category. With the following code i show all post from a category on a page with the page.php-template.

```
<?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(

'category_name' => 'fussball',
'paged' => $paged,
'posts_per_page' => 10
);

query_posts($args); ?>
```

Only Problem is, that sticky posts are ignored. So how must I change my code to show the sticky post on top?

Thanks for your anwsers,

Volker

Comment: So it seems that I found the solutions in this thread/post https://stackoverflow.com/a/52651341/11681862

Comment: Note: Please avoid `query_posts()`. Use custom query. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/